# JIRA / GreenHopper - How to follow the evolution of bugs?

Tags: bug-tracking, jira, greenhopper

I use JIRA in Agile mode (with GreenHopper plugin). The only type of issue that can be created is a User Story, and since the "Create Sub-Task" option is enabled, I can create Tasks from a User Story that will be their parent.

I'd like to follow bugs, that will be User Stories with type **FeedBack** (as, contrary to "standard" projects, I cannot create ER/PR records, User Story being the only one allowed):

- User Stories with at least a Task *Ongoing* should be *Started*
- User Stories with all Tasks *Done* should be *Done* too, etc

I tried to define filters via JQL but it does not seem to have such a power (`project = LOL AND issuetype = "User Story" AND "Story Type" = FeedBack AND...` I miss the possibility to check for Sub-tasks status).

The [JQL Tricks Plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JQLT/Home#) seems to offer such a functionnality (`hasSubtaskStatus()`), but its license has a cost...

Do you see/know any way ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the script runner plugin
https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/6820

You can find a couple of examples how-to
https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/GRV/Post+Functions

You can easily auto transition issues based on a set of business
rules.  ie. when we implemented similar scripts, we had to take
into account that a task is paused, such that the parent is affected
also.

Francis